# Update Adapter class view from a fragment activity

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application. In that, I have a fragment activity that creates the view for Adapter Class(`MyAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter`) in `onCreateView` method. Following is the snippet of code in `onCreateView` -

```
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The fragment activity which is `MyFragment` class receives broadcast data from some other class such as -

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastHelper.DEPARTURE_TIME)){
                Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
                if (args != null) {
                    int departure_time = args.getInt("Departure");
                    updateDepartureTime(departure_time);
                }
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastHelper.ARRIVAL_TIME)){
                Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
                if (args != null) {
                    int arrival_time = args.getInt("Arrival");
                    updateArrivalTime(arrival_time);
                   }
            }



        public void updateDepartureTime(int time){
            int d_time = time;
            }

        public void updateArrivalTime(int time){
            int a_time = time;
            }
```

So the values of `a_time` and `d_time` need to be sent to the view and updated in the textview of the view.There is a `viewHolder` in the MyAdapter class which displays the tetxview. How do I do it from MyFragment class

Answer (score 0):

Use some event bus library, https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus or https://github.com/square/otto.
If your data from broadcast comes from the same app, change broadcast also to event bus

If you want to use interface:

```
public interface OnChange{
    void onDepartureChanged(int value);
    void onArrivalChanged(int value);
}
```

in you activity implement it:

```
@Override
public void onDepartureChanged(int value) {
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

@Override
public void onArriChanged(int value) {
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

and pass it to your fragment, such like:

```
myFragment.registerOnValuesChange(this)
```

An, finally, when receiving in Broadcast:

```
public void updateDepartureTime(int time){
   int d_time = time;
   onValueListener.onDepratureChanged(d_time) 
}

public void updateArrivalTime(int time){
    int a_time = time;
    onValueListener.onArrivalChange(a_time) 
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do

Comment: Yes, you can use interface as listener, as described on pritish answer.

Comment: Can you explain with code how I could use... It would be helpful. My viewholder is in onbindView() which is an overriden method

Answer (score 0):

1) Use interface,extend it in your adapter. and set the value and do notifydatasetchanged().
2) Write a method in adapter which will update your view.Call it from your activty in your receiver of broadcast and call the method.In that method do notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: The second way of doing it which you have suggested can you please describe in more detail. It will be helpful

Comment: I am not sure what kind of data you are sending and how you are implementing it.....but generally speaking you must have send some data to adapter constructor which you are using as a view.Make it accessible throughout the class.Add a method like mupdate(data) {yourAdapterData=data } then notifydatasetchanged(). notify method will ensure that all your overridden methods are called once again and the new arraylist or the data which you send to adapter will overwrite the required data.

Comment: It is a int data... But my viewholder is in bindView(). how do i do this. Is it possible that you could help me with some code. I did not understand the other answer

Comment: how is bindview accessing that int in first instance ..??? when you load the adapter for first time..??? are you not sending it to its constructor...???

Comment: I have still not implemented it. I have the values in FragmentActivity. I need to send it to bindView() method in Adapter class and display in the UI. I am not sure of how to implement this. The two values a_time and d_time have to be updated for the same textview

Comment: Then please code it first. Without implementing it you won't get what we are saying. The variable which you use in first instance, you got to use it in set method and do notifydatasetchange(),but interface listener is always the preferred choice. It is clean and easy.

Comment: I am not sure about the coding part. Hence It would be helpful if you could help me in this